# TV series about teenagers who transform into beasts

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for an English-language, live-action TV series about teenagers (6 of them?) who transform into beasts.

I watched it in the late 90s or early 00s.

I remember they had yellow eyes.

Comment: When did you see it? Was it in English? Was it a cartoon or live-action series? Do you remember any names or descriptions besides "yellow eyes"? Was it a full length series, or a mini-series? Even seemingly small details could help us find this.

Comment: late 90s or early 00s, live action, full lenght, yes, in english, there were, I think, about six boys

Comment: for some reason when I think of it it reminds of supernatural

Comment: [Animorphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs_(TV_series))? Though that was 3 or 4 boys and 2 girls, not 6 boys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it may be [Animorphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs_(TV_series))

I do not remember the color of the eyes though.

Comment: animorphs had yellow eyes in the books for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the Animorphs, which is based on a very good YA book series.

The six: Jake, Cassie, Rachel, Marco, Tobias, and Ax. It was aired on Nickeloden, and starred Shawn Ashmore (later of X-Men fame) as Jake.